# How to ensure eclipse plugin has required bundles available?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, osgi

I'm just starting to develop a new eclipse plugin where I want a web application server running in Eclipse.  I found a nice blog, [OSGi as a Web Application Server](http://bryanhunt.wordpress.com/2010/05/14/osgi-as-a-web-application-server/), that describes how to do this.  The author suggests creating a target environment for my bundle requirements, and some of those bundles get pulled in from the Equinox Project SDK (now called Equinox Target Components in Juno).  I notice that the tutorial project runs fine when my target platform is the platform I created in the tutorial, but fails to start when it is the default platform.  So, now for my question...

If I need bundles that are not part of the default, how will my plugin project get access to those bundles?  Will I need to deploy them along with my plugin?  How would I know if the user's eclipse does or does not already have those required bundles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You was not much clear about what kind of application you are developing. Running a web server in an Eclipse IDE as a plugin don't make any sense to me. This kind of server application is best just running on top of Equinox.

Anyway, the right path is to create a "Product Configuration" file and add categories that contains the needed bundles (go to File/Plug-in Development/Product Configuration).

With this file you can run an instance of the product (inside the IDE) and can export it (create a zip containing all needed bundles)

And if you want to able your user to install plugin inside his IDE you must create a P2 repository (using a Target Definition File) and expose the exported directory within a Http server. You could research about Tycho to build this kind of components in a maven style.

Comment: There are good reasons for the app server within the plugin, but you answered the crux of the question: Product Configuration plus p2 is probably sufficient to get me back on the right track...  thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not sure if re-inventing the wheel again is really sufficient. 
You might take a look at [Pax-Web](https://github.com/ops4j/org.ops4j.pax.web) for inspiration on how to do it, or take a look [Apache Karaf](http://karaf.apache.org) as a OSGi-Container (using Pax-Web). Or even better start contributing to one of the two :-)

Comment: Thanks, but you misunderstood my question, the point is not what kind of plugin am I building but what do I do for my users, when an eclipse plugin I build requires bundles that are not part of the default target platform.  The fact that I am running a servlet in the plugin is only material to the problem, in that if one wants to read the tutorial they can verify the issue I described (the tutorial includes bundles from the Elipse Project SDK not found in the default target platform).